# Python dict.get() Lock

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, multiprocessing

When I use `dictionary.get()` function, is it locking the whole dictionary? I am developing a multiprocess and multithreading program. The dictionary is used to act as a state table to keep track of data. I have to impose a size limit to the dictionary, so whenever the limit is being hit, I have to do garbage collection on the table, based on the timestamp. The current implementation will delay adding operation while garbage collection is iterating through the whole table.

I will have 2 or more threads, one just to add data and one just to do garbage collection. Performance is *critical* in my program to handle streaming data. My program is receiving streaming data, and whenever it receives a message, it has to look for it in the state table, then add the record if it's non-existent in the first place, or copy certain information and then send it along the pipe.

I have thought of using `multiprocessing` to do the search and adding operation concurrently, but if I used processes, I have to make a copy of state table for each process, in that case, the performance overhead for synchronization is too high. And I also read that `multiprocessing.manager.dict()` is also locking the access for each CRUD operation. I could not spare the overhead for it so my current approach is using threading.

So my question is while one thread is doing `.get()`, `del dict['key']` operation on the table, will the other insertion thread be blocked from accessing it?

Note: I have read through most *SO*'s python dictionary related posts, but I cannot seem to find the answer. Most people only answer that even though python dictionary operations are atomic, it is safer to use a **Lock** for insertion/update. I'm handling a huge amount of streaming data so **Locking** every time is not ideal for me. Please advise if there is a better approach.

Comment: This doesn't address your main question so I'm making it a comment. Any time you're worried about race conditions, you want to use one-step operations. A two-step `get` then `del` is not advisable - use a one-step `pop` instead. I avoided the word "atomic" here since I don't think even the one-step approach can be atomic without extra effort in your case.

Comment: Thanks for comment. In my case, I designed the statutable such that the keys are all hash sum of value inside the dictionary's value. And it's generated at runtime, and I'm not keeping track of them. And pop requires to use *key* to `pop` item. I don't think I can use that for now. But changing 2 operation to 1 is a good idea.

Comment: How do you use `get` without a key?

Comment: Oh what I meant is that with `.get()` it returns None if the key is non-existent. But `.pop()` will raise `KeyError`. I have to do `for key in dict.keys()` anyway so it still have to do it twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the process of hashing or comparing the keys in your dictionary could invoke arbitrary Python code (basically, if the keys aren't all Python built-in types implemented in C, e.g. `str`, `int`, `float`, etc.), then yes, it would be possible for a race condition to occur in which the GIL is released while a bucket collision is being resolved (during the equality test), and another thread could leap in and cause the object being compared to to disappear from the `dict`. They try to ensure it doesn't actually crash the interpreter, but it has been a source of errors in the past.

If that's a possibility (or you're on a non-CPython interpreter, where there is no GIL providing basic guarantees like this), then you should really use a lock to coordinate access. On CPython, as long as you're on modern Python 3, the cost will be fairly low; contention on the lock should be fairly low since the GIL ensures only one thread is actually running at once; most of the time your lock should be uncontended (because the contention is on the GIL), so the incremental cost of using it should be fairly small.

A note: You might consider using `collections.OrderedDict` to simplify the process of limiting the size of your table. With `OrderedDict`, you can implement the size limit as a strict LRU (least-recently used) system by making additions to the table done as:

```
with lock:
    try:
        try:
            odict.move_to_end(key) # If key already existed, make sure it's "renewed"
        finally:
            odict[key] = value  # set new value whether or not key already existed
    except KeyError:
        # move_to_end raising key error means newly added key, so we might
        # have grown larger than limit
        if len(odict) > maxsize:
            odict.popitem(False)  # Pops oldest item
```

and usage done as:

```
with lock:
    # move_to_end optional; if using key means it should live longer, then do it
    # if only setting key should refresh it, omit move_to_end
    odict.move_to_end(key)
    return odict[key]
```

This does need a lock, but it also reduces the work for garbage collection when it grows too large from "check every key" (`O(n)` work) to "pop the oldest item off without looking at anything else" (`O(1)` work).

Comment: My keys are all string types. So does it mean that I don't have to care about race conditions? Your approach of popping oldest items is very good idea. It could save the program a lot of time.

Comment: @ThuYeinTun: If it's all `str` keys and you're on the CPython reference interpreter, then most individual function calls that affect a single item and most logically atomic actions will behave atomically, but that still limits you; if you need to do two things (even something that looks like one thing, like `mydict[key] += 1` is really multiple steps that could conflict across threads and end up dropping increments), then all uses of the `dict` will need locking to ensure that the multistage operations behave atomically.

Answer (score 0):

A lock is used to avoid race conditions so no two threads could make change to the dict at the same time so it is advisible that you use the lock else you might go into a race condition causing program to fail. A mutex lock can be used to deal with 2 threads.